# play pls file in browser

Tags: javascript, flash, html, audio, shoutcast

I need to play a `pls` file in my website, so that each user can listen to it.
One way is to use Flash and actionscript, but I've been searching for another way to play it in the browser using JavaScript or HTML5.

Is there a way to play `pls` files in the browser using html5 or javascript?

Comment: yes, a pls contains a list of music files and locations, also url's for streaming

Comment: @cuzzea - The point is how do you extract those urls.

Answer (score 1):

A pls file has this format:

```
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=x
File1=http://80.86.106.136:80/
File2=http://80.86.106.136:80/
...
```

so you would need to read the content and do something like this

```
var content = readPls();
var data = content.split('\n\r');
var number_of_files = data[1].replace('NumberOfEntries=','');
var files = [];
for(var i=0;i<number_of_files;i++){
    files.push(data[2+i].replace("File"+(i+1),''))
}
```

code needs work, but this is the way to go about it (in js/as)

Comment: just use <audio src="http://serverIP/;stream.nsv&type=mp3&quot"; controls="controls"> script